# Python : curl command option with `-d` to python

Tags: python, unix, curl, python-requests

Python : curl command option with `-d` to python

I have the following `curl` bash script that returns multiple lines in terminal.

```
curl 'http://localhost/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query" :{ 
    "range" : {
      "created_at" : {
        "gte": "now-2h",
        "lte": "now"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I want to run this bash script or `curl` command in python and receive the output in python. What should I do? `requests` does not seem to support options for `curl` command.

Comment: Do you just want to call `curl` as an external program?

Comment: See also [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: No I want to call inside script that I can edit the command

Comment: What do you mean by *"edit the command"*?

Comment: See also [Convert post request performed by curl to python request based on requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009332/convert-post-request-performed-by-curl-to-python-request-based-on-requests-modul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have understand, you want to send JSON in post-data with Python. In requests you can do it like this:

```
import requests, json

data =  {
   "query": { 
    "range" : {
      "created_at" : {
        "gte": "now-2h",
        "lte": "now"
      }
    }
  }
}

url = "http://localhost/_search?pretty"

response = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(data))
```

Requesting ElasticSearch in python was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930235/querying-elasticsearch-with-python-requests-not-working-fine).